# Print PCL file using LPR in C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing, window, lpr

I'm trying to print `pcl` file using `lpr` command. here my C# application create a new process to invoke `lpr` command with argument includes `pcl` file name and few more.

but now i'm facing issue because lpr command only accept 128 length file names. But my pcl file path longer than that. I tried to set the process working directory as the `pcl` file folder. although I set it, lpr.exe refer the absolute path to check the file existence.

Is there any innovative idea to get rid from this file path length issue?

```
Proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = pcl_file.Directory.ToString();
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lpr";
Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Proc.Start();
```

Comment: don't do that, why can't your copy/paste you pcl file int debug/relase folder of you project?

Answer (score 0):

A quick cheat might be to use the short filename.  Use [Getshortpath](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9f5db73-3ddd-4be3-974e-64ecf5f9c4a3/obtaining-the-short-83-filename-from-a-long-filename?forum=netfxbcl)